# Couldn't connect to accessibility bus

Tags: ssh, dbus, x11-forwarding

When using `ssh` with X11 forwarding, I am getting various errors and warnings when running gui applications.

As an example, any time I am running [gitg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/gitg), I get the following warning:

```
** (gitg:15904): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ychCoQcrqT: Connection refused
```

Besides being ugly, does that suggest any real error?

I get the same warning running [evince](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/evince):

```
** (evince:16634): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ychCoQcrqT: Connection refused
```

... or [eog](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/eog):

```
** (eog:16872): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ychCoQcrqT: Connection refused
```

And so on.

Perhaps it worth mentioning: I am connecting from 12.04 to (yes, unsupported) 13.04.

Comment: It can be related to the problem of dbus not being found.
Look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188877/32769 (shell code to have SSH properly use dbus)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think the warnings are important (unless you need the accessibility bus). Apparently forwarding the accessibility bus over SSH isn't supported yet.

However, you could try the following to suppress the errors if it annoys you:

Prepend the following to any commands:

```
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

Or (a long-shot) try using the `-Y` option with `-X` in SSH to enable trusted forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I had disabled conda with:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
source ~/.bashrc
```

After this, when I started GDL, similar error was thrown at me. Fixed with:

```
conda init bash
```

Hope it works for others.